# 'mat-menu-item' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have angular app 'Angular: 15.2.2', and I want to use material, the mat-menu is recognized while the mat-menu-item is not recognized.
@angular/material@15.2.2

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  <mat-icon>notifications</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <mat-menu-item>Notification 1</mat-menu-item>
</mat-menu>
```

I already imported the modules in the app module

```
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule ,
```

from import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';

Comment: Try to use it as a directive `<button mat-menu-item>Notification 1</button>`

Answer (score 3):

Like said by @nils-kähler you should use the directive mat-menu-item:

```
<button mat-menu-item>Notification 1</button>
```

You can find some examples here : https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples